# Define alias and getter/setter function only if type exists in a class

Tags: c++, sfinae, partial-specialization, interface-class

I am provided with a set of classes that I cannot alter. (For the curious: these are automatically generated from Simulink models) These classes unfortunately make too many things publicly available. So, I decided to write an interface class for all these classes that encapsulates them and makes using them a little safer. However, I am having trouble to write one interface class (template) that works for all possible classes that might occur.

Most of the classes define a structure called `MyStruct` that I need to use within the interface class. I do not want to use that name, though, for various reasons and would like to use an alias within the interface class instead. So, I ended up with the following code:

```cpp
// Classes to interface with
class MyClass1
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double f1;
        double f2;
    } _myVar {};
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double g1;
        double g2;
        double g3;
    } _myVar {};
};

class MyClass3
{};

// Interface class
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
public:
    using MyAlias = typename T::MyStruct;

    void setVar(const MyAlias& newVar) {_object._myVar = newVar;};
    
    void doSomething()
    {
        MyAlias inputs {};
    }
private:
    T _object {};
};


// Main function
int main()
{
    Interface<MyClass1> i1; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass2> i2; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass3> i3; // compile error: no type named ‘MyStruct’ in ‘class MyClass3’
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile because `MyClass3` does not define the type `MyStruct`. Therefore, the alias cannot be defined.

I tried to look into defining the alias and method only if the type is defined and stumbled upon the SFINAE concept. Unfortunately, I cannot use anything from the standard library in my code. So, things like `std::enable_if` or `std::void_t` are off the table. Artificial *intelligence* came up with the following solutions for the alias and the method:

```cpp
template<typename U, typename = void>
struct check_mystruct {using type = void; };
template<typename U>
struct check_mystruct<U, decltype((void)U::MyStruct, void())> { using type = typename U::MyStruct; };
using MyAlias = typename check_mystruct<T>::type;
```

```cpp
template<typename U = MyAlias>
void setVar(const U& newVar) {_object._myVar = newVar;};
void setVar(...) { /* do nothing */ };
```

As far as I understand it, this should work. The partial specialization of the `check_mystruct` struct and the templated version of the method should only be used if `S::MyStruct` exists.
However, if I put it together into the initial program like this:

```cpp
// Classes to interface with
class MyClass1
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double f1;
        double f2;
    } _myVar {};
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double g1;
        double g2;
        double g3;
    } _myVar {};
};

class MyClass3
{};

// Interface class
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
public:
    template<typename U, typename = void>
    struct check_mystruct {using type = void; };
    template<typename U>
    struct check_mystruct<U, decltype((void)U::MyStruct, void())> { using type = typename U::MyStruct; };
    
    using MyAlias = typename check_mystruct<T>::type;
    
    template<typename U = MyAlias>
    void setVar(const U& newVar) {_object._myVar = newVar;};
    void setVar(...) { /* do nothing */ };
    
    void doSomething()
    {
        MyAlias inputs {};
    }
private:
    T _object {};
};


// Main function
int main()
{
    Interface<MyClass1> i1; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass2> i2; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass3> i3; // compiles fine
    
    i1.doSomething(); // compile error: In instantiation of ‘void Interface<T>::doSomething() [with T = MyClass1]’: variable or field ‘inputs’ declared void
    i2.doSomething();
    i3.doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error saying

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Interface<T>::doSomething() [with T = MyClass1]’:
main.cpp:58:19:   required from here
main.cpp:44:17: error: variable or field ‘inputs’ declared void
   44 |         MyAlias inputs {};
      |                 ^~~~~~
```

So, the alias is set to `void` even though `MyClass` has a type `MyStruct`. I do not understand this. Can someone explain what went wrong? Is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: On topic: Regarding encapsulation, if you can't use SFINAE "reliably", what about PIMPL? Off topic: excuse my curiosity, but why can't you use STL?

Comment: CppReference shows how to "roll your own" versions of [void_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) and [enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: @TheNomad I head not heard of pImpl before. After quickly reading up on it, I cannot see how that would help me with creating the alias and the method. Regarding the standard library: I am working on the opensource flightcontroller firmware PX4 and, as far as I know, I cannot use that library there.

Comment: @tbxfreeware That is worth looking into. However, I am still wondering why my code fails. Obviously, I must be misunderstanding something about the syntax of these partial template specializations but I cannot find out what it is.

Comment: @fritut08 PIMPL is mostly about encapsulation. I was not trying to fix your alias issue. As I said, I only focused on the sentence I quoted to tell you about a different approach which might be easier to "hide" exposed data, while also providing the same "original" functionality **IF** you did not want to use SFINAE.

Answer (score 3):

With C++20, and specialization with concept, you might do

```
// Interface class
template <typename T>
class Interface
{
public:
    void doSomething() {}
    // ...
private:
    T _object {};
};

template<typename T>
requires (requires {
    typename T::MyStruct;
})
class Interface<T>
{
public:
    
    using MyAlias = typename T::MyStruct;
    
    void setVar(const MyAlias& newVar) {_object._myVar = newVar;};
    
    void doSomething()
    {
        [[maybe_unused]]MyAlias inputs {};
    }
private:
    T _object {};
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/scdMcKarj)

Comment: OP - check out Sandor Dargo's book "C++ Concepts" - it's a great introduction.  Also see his blog articles "How to write your own C++ concepts".

Answer (score 1):

> So, the alias is set to void even though MyClass has a type MyStruct. I do not understand this. Can someone explain what went wrong?

I was expecting this error to occur `[with T = MyClass3]`, rather than `MyClass1`. That is when `MyAlias` becomes an alias for type `void`. Since you cannot have an object of type `void`, the declaration of variable `inputs` will trigger an error.

> Is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do?

You could add yet more SFINAE to disable the declaration of variable `inputs` when `MyAlias` is type `void`. There is, however, a much simpler approach. Write a partial specialization for class `Interface` that is used only when type `T` has a member type `MyStruct`.

The implementation below uses a "roll-your-own" definition for `void_t` that I found on CppReference. This complies the with OP's specification that `std::void_t` cannot be used.

```cpp
// main.cpp
namespace tbx
{
    // Definitions for C++11 from CppReference
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

    template< typename... Ts>
    struct make_void { typedef void type; };

    template< typename... Ts>
    using void_t = typename tbx::make_void<Ts...>::type;
}

// Classes to interface with
class MyClass1
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double f1;
        double f2;
    } _myVar{};
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double g1;
        double g2;
        double g3;
    } _myVar{};
};

class MyClass3
{};

// Interface class
// The base template for class `Interface` makes no mention 
// of type `MyStruct`.
template<typename T, typename = void>
class Interface
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {}
private:
    T _object{};
};

// Interface class
// The partial specialization will be selected when type `T` 
// defines member type `MyStruct`.
template<typename T>
class Interface<T, typename tbx::void_t<typename T::MyStruct>>
{
public:
    using MyAlias = typename T::MyStruct;

    void setVar(const MyAlias& newVar) { _object._myVar = newVar; };

    void doSomething()
    {
        MyAlias inputs{};
    }
private:
    T _object{};
};

// Main function
int main()
{
    Interface<MyClass1> i1; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass2> i2; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass3> i3; // compiles fine
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Enable individual members of the `Interface`

In his comment below, the OP indicates that he has three different `MyStruct` types that are part of the `Interface`: `MyStructA`, `MyStructB`, and `MyStructC`.

The following program shows a variation of class template `Interface` in which each member function can be enabled or disabled individually. Note the idiomatic use of `typename U = T`. This forces the compiler to defer, for instance, the evaluation of `typename U::MyStruct inputs{};`, until the template is actually instantiated.

The techniques used here serve as an example on how to "turn on and off" different members based on the presence or absence of `MyStructA`, `MyStructB`, and `MyStructC`.

CppReference supplied the code for a "roll-your-own" version of `enable_if_t`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
namespace tbx
{
    // Definitions for C++11 from CppReference
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

    template< typename... Ts>
    struct make_void { typedef void type; };

    template< typename... Ts>
    using void_t = typename tbx::make_void<Ts...>::type;

    // Also from CppReference
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

    template<bool B, class T = void>
    struct enable_if {};

    template<class T>
    struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

    template< bool B, class T = void >
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B, T>::type;
}

// has_MyStruct_v
template< typename T, typename = void >
struct has_MyStruct {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
template< typename T >
struct has_MyStruct<T, tbx::void_t<typename T::MyStruct>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
template< typename T >
static constexpr bool has_MyStruct_v = has_MyStruct<T>::value;

// Classes to interface with
class MyClass1
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double f1;
        double f2;
    } _myVar{};
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        double g1;
        double g2;
        double g3;
    } _myVar{};
};

class MyClass3
{};

// Interface class
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
public:
    template< typename U = T, typename = tbx::enable_if_t<has_MyStruct_v<U>>>
    using MyAlias = typename U::MyStruct;

    template< typename U = T, typename = tbx::enable_if_t<has_MyStruct_v<U>>>
    void setVar(const MyAlias<U>& newVar) { _object._myVar = newVar; };

    template< typename U = T, typename = tbx::enable_if_t<has_MyStruct_v<U>>>
    void setVar2(const typename U::MyStruct& newVar) { _object._myVar = newVar; };

    template< typename U = T, typename = tbx::enable_if_t<has_MyStruct_v<U>>>
    void doSomething()
    {
        MyAlias<U> inputs{};             // this works
        typename U::MyStruct inputs2{};  // and this, too!
    }
private:
    T _object{};
};

// Main function
int main()
{
    Interface<MyClass1> i1; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass2> i2; // compiles fine
    Interface<MyClass3> i3; // compiles fine

    i1.doSomething();
    i2.doSomething();

    i1.setVar({});
    i2.setVar({});

    i1.setVar2({});
    i2.setVar2({});
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Comment: This looks very promising. However, my actual problem is a little more complicated than this simplified model. In reality, I do not only have a single MyStruct to watch for but 3 (MyStructA, MyStructB and MyStructC). With your approach, I would have to write a specialization for every possible combination (1. none of the structs are defined, 2. only MyStructA is defined, 3. MyStructA and MyStructB are defined, ... 8. all MyStructs are defined).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [boost](/questions/tagged/boost), you could use [Boost.PFR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_pfr) to create individual getters for all the fields in `_myVar` and specify exactly for what fields there should be setters.

In case `T` doesn't have a `MyStruct`, `MyAlias` will alias a `struct` with no member variables instead. Of course, no getters and setters will then be useable, but the rest of the functions that doesn't depend on `MyStruct` can still be used.

```cpp
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>

template <class T, std::size_t... S>
class Interface {
    template <class, class = void>
    struct get_alias_def { struct type {}; }; // for T's without MyStruct

    template <class A>
    struct get_alias_def<A, std::void_t<typename A::MyStruct>> {
        using type = A::MyStruct;
    };

public:
    using MyAlias = typename get_alias_def<T>::type;

    static constexpr size_t field_count = boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<MyAlias>;

    template <std::size_t F>
    using field_type = boost::pfr::tuple_element_t<F, MyAlias>;

    static_assert(((S < field_count) && ...), "Setter index out of bounds");

    template <std::size_t F> // one getter per field
    const auto& get() const {
        static_assert(F < field_count, "F is out of bounds");
        return boost::pfr::get<F>(_object._myVar);
    }

    // setters for the fields specified in S...
    template <std::size_t F>
    void set(const field_type<F>& value) {
        static_assert(((F == S) || ...), "No setter for field");
        boost::pfr::get<F>(_object._myVar) = value;
    }

    template <std::size_t F>
    void set(field_type<F>&& value) {
        static_assert(((F == S) || ...), "No setter for field");
        boost::pfr::get<F>(_object._myVar) = std::move(value);
    }

    void doSomething() { /*...*/ }

private:
    T _object{};
};
```

Usage example:

```cpp
int main() {
    Interface<MyClass3> i3;
    // i3.get<0>();                    // error: no fields available

    Interface<MyClass2, 1, 2> i2;      // only field 1 and 2 has setters
    i2.set<1>(3.141);                  // ok, setter defined
    std::cout << i2.get<1>() << '\n';  // 3.141

    // i2.set<0>(3.141);               // error, "No setter for field"
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G57anabnW)